# Is there a specific test for correlation between 2 measurable variables between nominal data?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, ancova, manova

I am having a hard time finding a comparable test for my data set. Here is what I have: weight of individuals and Concentration of a trace metal in each individual for 8 field sites.

I want to see if all sites have the same relationship between weight and conc'.

An ANCOVA looks like it would be perfect but Im not sure if it is appropriate. From my understanding, an ANCOVA is basically comparing two or more linear regressions. Sounds great except I am not trying to model my data, I am trying to look for a relationship or correlation.

I have played with the idea of using a GLM but I think that would still be the same issues as an ANCOVA.

Is there a test that can compare correlations? Or would a ANCOVA still be the best way to approach this?

Comment: ANCOVA sounds like what you want if you care about the 8 field sites.

Comment: between nominal data ?  How many individuals ? in each individual for 8 field sites ( do you mean weight of same indivual at 8 sites ?  do field sites have similar 
conditions or vary ?

Comment: It seems that the problem could be handled if you compute corrrelation for each site and then postulate a meta-analytic hypothesis of equivalence of sample correlations. Indicate details of your data including samples/number of individuals.

Comment: Im sorry here is the requested information: 

- weight and concentration are measurable data, the 8 sites would be nominal. 
- Sample sizes: 8 individuals per site, 8 sites

The field sites have similar conditions, but may have different abiotic factors that were unmeasured. The data collected post a large storm (hurricane). Therefore we are trying to tease out whether the hurricane was an effect, or if the individuals in fact have similar accumulation patterns. There are more biological mechanisms behind our reasoning but it wouldn't effect our choice of statistical analysis